# Problem computing a complex line integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to evaluate the function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: z \mapsto \overline{z}$ over the curve $C$ which is the union of the line from 0 to 1 and the line from 1 to 1+$i$.

So, let's consider the following parametrization of $C$:

$$\sigma: [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: t \mapsto \begin{cases} t, & t\in [0,1]\\ 1+i(t-1),& t\in (1,2]
\end{cases}$$

This function clearly is differentiable on [0,1), and $(1,2]$. But, when I compute the left and right limits in $1$, they are different.  I need this derivative to compute the line integral. So what am I missing here?

The definition of a line integral is $\int_C f(z) dz = \int_{[a,b]} f(\sigma(t)) \sigma'(t) dt$, where the domain of sigma is $[a,b]$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you provide some context regarding the definitions? Usually you don't need differentiability here.

Comment: @GitGud, added the definition of the line integral we use.

Comment: Thank you. What about restrictions on $f$?

Comment: $f$ should just be continuous.

Comment: If you know about juxtaposition (I don't know if this is the right word in english) of curves, you can use Nicholas' answer.

Comment: @GitGud I usually see the term concatenation used in this context.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson Thanks, makes sense. In my language we use the word for juxtaposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is this: yes, smoothness of the curve is important for parameterization formulas.  However, you need to remember that integrals are additive objects -- and you can easily split this curve in to two separate pieces, each of which can be parameterized smoothly with no difficulty.

Let $\gamma_1$ be the line segment from $0$ to $1$, and $\gamma_2$ the line segment from $1$ to $1+i$. Then you can write
$$
\int_C\bar{z}\,dz=\int_{\gamma_1}\bar{z}\,dz+\int_{\gamma_2}\bar{z}\,dz.
$$
From here, parameterize each of the two curves separately.

Comment: I wanted to split it, but I was unsure what to do with the point 1.

Comment: It's safe to include it in each.  The overlap that you get will just be the integral over a single point -- which is 0.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!